# java.sql.SQLException: No data found with MS Access database

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access

I'm using java with an MS Access database.

When I try to search the data in the database I get this message:

> java.sql.SQLException: No data found

in my database a row is empty, the database looks like this:

> **DATA_TO_READ**
>
> 1-->*string1*
>
> 2-->*string2*
>
> 3-->
>
> 4-->*string4*

The error message appears when I try to read line 3. I think it's normal because there is no data. This is why I make a verification in order to know if there is some data:

```
while(data.read())
{
    ExtractString = (data.getString("DATA_TO_READ")!=null) ? data.getString("DATA_TO_READ") : "";
}
```

But even with this verification I still have the same issue.

Does someone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: PLease show the query.

Comment: maybe writing your instruction inside a `try { ... }  catch { ... } block?

Comment: The problem with the try catch block is that it may shadow other SQL exceptions.

Comment: I haven't the query because i'm actually not in work, but the query should be something like "SELECT DATA_TO_READ to [my table]".
This block is inside a try{} catch{}, when i made "step by step debug" netbean jump to catch when data reading fail, it's why i have "java.sql.SQLException: No data found" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to read the value of a column multiple times.Change the code like that :

```
    while(data.read())
{
    String val = data.getString("DATA_TO_READ");
    ExtractString = (val !=null) ? val : "";
}
```